# как удалить элемент

Tags: jquery

Как удалить запись из таблицы с id="22" ?

```
<table>
    <tr id="22">
     <th><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
     <th>Первая запись</th>
    </tr>
</table>

$(document).on('click', '.fa-trash', function() {
   // Код ???
});
```

Comment: Точнее запись с таблицы <tr id="22">

Answer (score 0):

Используйте $('id или class элемента').remove();

```
$(document).on('click', '.fa-trash', function() {
      $('table #22').remove();
});
```

Comment: А если id изначально не известно ?

Comment: Тогда ищете первый элемент так:
$('table').find('tr').eq(0).remove();

тут подробней с примерами
https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: @DmytroRomanenko, а если это не первый элемент, а 10?)

Comment: При выводе такой структуры формировать id, формировать дополнительные data-{} дата атрибуты, то есть максимально продумать вывод с данными, что бы удобней и точней искать нужный элемент.

Answer (score 0):

У вас тут несколько элементов с одинаковым id, поэтому советую удалять так:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fa-trash', function() {
      $('tr[id="22"]').remove();
});
```

А еще лучше - пропишите понятные классы для элементов и работайте с классами (row[data-id="22"]).

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю удалять через this. Поднимайтесь вверх до нужного элемента и удаляйте его.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fa-trash').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте таблице какой-то id, на случай, если таблиц станет несколько. Например id='tab1'. Тогда так, например:

```
let tab = document.getElementById('tab1');
let forDelete = document.getElementById('22'); // в общем случае лучше пользовать querySelectorAll() и передавать класс
Array.prototype.map.call(forDelete, row => {
    tab.removeChild(row);
});
```

P. S. И да, не используйте одинаковые id.